# Laravel find amount of time between 2 dates that are within opening hours

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

```
 $minutes = (int)ceil((float)$this->quotes()
        ->whereRaw(\DB::raw("quotes.created_at >= STR_TO_DATE('".$from->format('d/m/Y')." 00:00', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i')"))
        ->whereRaw(\DB::raw("quotes.created_at <= STR_TO_DATE('".$to->format('d/m/Y')." 23:59', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i')"))
        ->whereRaw('completed_at IS NOT NULL')
        ->whereRaw("completed_at <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ")
        ->groupBy('branch_id')
        ->avg(\DB::raw('TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, created_at, completed_at)')));
```

Above is my current way of finding the average minutes between created_at and completed_at for quotes. I am wanting to not include minutes that are outside opening hours. I've created a table with opening_hours and Mon-Sun with what days active and what the opening hours are for that day e.g. opening_time 08:30 closing_time 17:00.
I was unsure on how to approach this to only average the minutes that are within Mon-Friday 08:30 - 17:00.

Comment: What do you want to end up with?

Answer (score 0):

```
    $quotes = $this->quotes()
        ->select(\DB::raw("*, DATEDIFF(completed_at, created_at) AS DaysToComplete"))
        ->whereRaw(\DB::raw("quotes.created_at >= STR_TO_DATE('".$from->format('d/m/Y')." 00:00', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i')"))
        ->whereRaw(\DB::raw("quotes.created_at <= STR_TO_DATE('".$to->format('d/m/Y')." 23:59', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i')"))
        ->whereRaw('completed_at IS NOT NULL')
        ->whereRaw("completed_at <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ")
        ->get();

    /**
     * Puts Opening Hours into an array using
     * DateTime/Carbon DayOfWeek as key
     * these keys are saved against
     * each day within the
     * opening hours
     * table
     *
     * SUNDAY                       // int(0)
     * MONDAY                       // int(1)
     * TUESDAY                      // int(2)
     * WEDNESDAY                    // int(3)
     * THURSDAY                     // int(4)
     * FRIDAY                       // int(5)
     * SATURDAY                     // int(6)
     */
    $opening_hours = OpeningHour::all();
    foreach($opening_hours as $hours){
        $hrs[$hours->day] = [
            'day' => $hours->day,
            'name' => $hours->name,
            'opening_time' => $hours->opening_time,
            'closing_time' => $hours->closing_time,
            'active' => $hours->active,

        ];
    }
    $quote_completion_time = array();
    foreach($quotes as $quote){
        $created_at = $quote->created_at;
        $completed_at = $quote->completed_at;
        $minutes = 0;
        for($i = 0;$i <= $quote->DaysToComplete;$i++){
            /**
             * Manipulates the opening_time and closing_time to the same
             * day so that you can check the diffInMinutes between 2
             * carbon instances for the same day
             */
            $opening_time = \Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $created_at->format('Y-m-d') . ' ' . $hrs[$created_at->dayOfWeek]['opening_time']);
            $closing_time = \Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $created_at->format('Y-m-d') . ' ' . $hrs[$created_at->dayOfWeek]['closing_time']);
            /**
             * Checks if the day is active within opening hours
             * that is set within the opening hours table
             */
            if($hrs[$created_at->dayOfWeek]['active'] == 1){
                if($quote->DaysToComplete == 0){
                    //For quotes that are created and completed on the same day
                    $minutes += $created_at->diffInMinutes($completed_at);
                } elseif($i == 0){
                    // The first day of a quote opening but not being completed in the same day
                    $minutes += $created_at->diffInMinutes($closing_time);
                }elseif($i == $quote->DaysToComplete){
                    //The day the quote was completed
                    $minutes += $opening_time->diffInMinutes($completed_at);
                }else{
                    //full days where the quote was open but not completed
                    $minutes += $opening_time->diffInMinutes($closing_time);
                }

            }
            //Add day to created_at ready for the next checks
            $created_at->addDay();
        }
        $quote_completion_time[] = $minutes;
    }

    $quotes_collection = collect($quote_completion_time);
    $minutes = $quotes_collection->avg();

    if (empty($minutes)){
        return 'N/A';
    }

    return \Carbon\CarbonInterval::create(0, 0, 0, floor($minutes/1440), floor(($minutes % 1440)/60), $minutes%60, 0);
```

Here is what I ended up doing. My table of opening hours has a field called day which matches the day of the week with DateTime